# Windows batch command for multiple folders creation 0001 - 1000

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create folders named 0001 to 1000 using a batch command.
Folder names should be all 4 digits, ie: 0001, 0002, 0999 - 1000.

I've already tried this command line:

```
for /L %%g in (1,1,1000) do (md %%g)
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  When you tried the command in the question, what was the result?

Comment: Use 4 separate commands for to create folders 0001-0009, 0010-0099, 0100-0999 and 1000 respectively. It is the simplest solution I think.

Comment: it created folder 1,2,3 and so on...but what i need is 4 digits standard in folder name..

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following (in a batch file):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,1000) do set n=0000%%i& echo !n:~-4!
```

This gives

```
0001
0002
0003
...
```